# Procedure returning 0 instead of higher number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following procedure to retrieve some data, based by the year, which is input by the user. However, I always get a 0 back. I'm still fairly new to SQL, but this seemed like it should work

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Yearly]
@year int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @yearly Datetime
DECLARE @summ int   

SELECT @summ = SUM([dbo].[Out].[OutPcs]), @yearly = [dbo].[Out].[DateTime]
FROM [dbo].[Out]
WHERE YEAR(@yearly) = @year
GROUP BY [Out].[DateTime]
END;
```

Should I have used nested select statements? I suspect something is wrong in that part of the procedure.

Comment: You  are missing a`RETURN @sum `just before the `END;`   Either that or you want to do the SELECT without the `@sum =` if you want to return it as a row

Comment: I thought of that, but it still returns a 0 when I run it with parameter 2018. I basically want to return only one cell, which is the sum of the OutPcs of the year that the user input.

Comment: Replace the WHERE clause with WHERE YEAR([dbo].[Out].[DateTime]) = @year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `DECLARE @yearly Datetime`.

You attempt to set it in `SELECT ... @yearly = Out.Datetime FROM Out`, but then you have this `WHERE` statement: `YEAR(@yearly) = @year`

This returns nothing since `@yearly` is `NULL` when called by `YEAR()`

This makes the statement equivalent to `WHERE NULL = 2018`

Which will never be true.

To fix this, you need to set yearly before calling it in your `WHERE` clause or use something else there.

It looks like you want to use `YEAR(Dbo.Out.Datetime)` instead there

---

Since it looks like you're new to `SQL` I will add some extra explanation. This is an oversimplification.

Most programming languages run top to bottom. Executing the line1 first, line2 second, line3 third, and so on. `SQL` does not do this.

The command `SELECT Name FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = 1` Runs in the following order.

```
First  - FROM Employee    --> Load the Employee table 
Second - WHERE EmpID = 1  --> Scan Employee for the records where EmpID = 1
Third  - SELECT Name      --> Display the `Name` field of the records I found.
```

Your command looks like this to the `SQL` `compiler`

```
First   - FROM dbo.Out   --> Load Out table 
Second  - WHERE YEAR(@yearly) = @year --> Scan for records that meet this req.
Third   - SELECT ... @yearly = dbo.Out.Datetime --> Set @yearly to the [Datetime] field associated to the record(s) I found.
```

Note that if your statement had returned multiple records, then `SQL` would have tried to set your `1-dimensional` variable to an array of values. It would fail and give you something like

> Too many records returned. Have me only return 1 record.

Answer (score 1):

Why your code is not working is well explained by [@Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212696/5142585)

Here is a working code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Yearly]
    @year int
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT SUM([dbo].[Out].[OutPcs])
    FROM [dbo].[Out]
    WHERE YEAR([dbo].[Out].[DateTime]) = @year

END;
```

Comment: This one worked, but why? Mine looked the same, I just used variables.

Comment: Check Edwards explanation. Basically, in this line `WHERE YEAR(@yearly) = @year` your `@yearly` was `null`.

Answer (score 0):

**You forgot to return "summ":**

And @yearly var is not necessary.

Group by Year is not necessary too.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Yearly]
    @year int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @summ int   

    SELECT @summ = SUM([dbo].[Out].[OutPcs])
    FROM [dbo].[Out]
    WHERE YEAR([dbo].[Out].[DateTime]) = @year

    Return @summ
END;
```